# How to find the current and Resistance?

Tags: voltage, current, current-measurement, current-source

Ok Everyone DownVoted! i am sorry about the diagram! **So i Updated it**

this is my new diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPvLqu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Then Now how to find I1? what is the math behind it ?**

**and one more ...**

Suppose if i have a 13V10A battery  what resistor(i mean resistance & watts ) is needed to convert it to 13V2A (  math behind it ?)

Comment: We have an awesome on-site schematic editor, which you can start-up with Ctrl-M.

Comment: oops! sorry 4 that!

Comment: why -1? here? mmm

Comment: Please update your question with the proposed schematic editor. Can you explain the difference between I1 and I2? Where did you get these numbers from?

Comment: Second question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The downvotes are probably because your question amounts to "I have no clue about electricity; please tutor me about the absolute basics". The behavior of the site visitors is such that these kinds of questions get downvoted.

Comment: I am also confused by the question and circuit... Is there only 1 resistor (R1)? The current through every series component in a closed loop is identical. The numbers you have supplied do not make sense compared to the components and connections you show. Check out this basic tutorial on my website about circuits:
http://www.projectsbykec.com/projects/tutorials/circuit-theory
Then this basic guide to circuit analysis:
http://www.projectsbykec.com/projects/tutorials/circuit-analysis

Comment: I don't think its the level of the question, but I can see that "diagram" being a cause for downvotes.  You really have to look at it carefully and decipher it just to get what a schematic would have told you immediately.

Comment: If your circuit requires 2A and you have a 10A supply then the supply will only give out 2A. The current associated with the supply is the maximum that it can give.

Comment: i have updated the Q! Please Answer if possible!

Comment: @IOIOMAD Answer: [Ohm's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)

Answer (score 2):

The typed schematic you provided, if I read it right, is the following

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft99de.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is not right. Either the schematic is not right, or the current is not right.

This circuit follows ohms law

\$ V = IR \$ or \$I = \frac{V}{R} \$

From your schematic, the current is 13A (by plugging in the values into the formula above).

Current in a loop does not change, so current entering the resistor is the same current leaving the resistor, so I1=I2. For the schematic, I1 = 13A, and I2= 13A.

If the I2 current of 6.8A WAS correct, then you're schematic is wrong, and it should be

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fis8Tl.png)</sup>

Using the same formula as above, the current in this circuit is ~ 6.8.

In a real world example, the current would probably be 0A for either schematic, because you have a 1W resistor which is not enough to dissipate the power, and would burn.

The second question, if you have a 13V source that can provide 10A, it doesn't mean that all 10A will go rush through the circuit. The circuit will take as much as it needs. If you're circuit is drawing 10A, then by increasing the resistance, you will decrease the current in the circuit. You can use the formula above to determine what resistance you need to get 2A, or any arbitrary current that is within the limits of your source.

Comment: i have updated the Q! Please Answer if possible!

Comment: This is still the best answer anybody can give, even with the change from 13V to 10V. The only difference is that the theoretical current would now be 10A instead of 13A (with "perfect" components), or if you take the current measurement AM1 as being correct, IM1 is still exactly the same (also 6.8A), but that would mean that some of the other components in your (voltage source or resistor) actually have other values (e.g. less than 10V for the voltage source and/or higher than 1 Ohm resistance on the resistor).